# Symfony ClassNotFoundException - JwtAuthenticator

Tags: php, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

Im working on a existing project, which uses symfony to provide web services. I'm new to Symfony technology but I have good experience in Laravel, the project has an issue in JwtAuthenticator.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException
>   Attempted to load class "JwtAuthenticator" from namespace

Thing is this issue does not occur in windows OS, but while working in linux Ubuntu it occurs, so far what I found is that the cache data seems to trouble, also unable to delete them without changing the folder access permission to 777. But once if it is given full access permission and if the cache folder is emptied then application runs without error, but from the next request it again happens. So if removing files in cache is done then it works.

Here, JwtAuthenticator is used to provide authentication verification

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Which webserver are you using to run the code? apache, nginx, the development web server integrated with symfony? It looks like a permission problem.

Comment: If you're using Apache, try `chown -R www-data` to the `var/` folder

Comment: @monstercode, hi thanks for your reply, Im using apache server. Yes its the permission problem only, is there any way to solve this

Comment: @Mathieu Dormeval , hi thanks for your reply, I did that chown -R www-data to the var/ folder,but still no improvement. Also I tried symfony 3 docs workout like adding **unmask(0000)** in web dir -> app.php, app_dev.php and bin/console too. But no change..

Comment: Make sure you have a backup of your `vendor/` directory and run `composer update`